# Could IE8/9 screen.width variable ever report different resolutions on a single device?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics

In analytics data, IE8/9 appear to be reporting different, sometimes non-standard resolutions from screen.width / height on the same device, for instance: 1140x641, 1366x768, 1249x702. Those variables are supposed to report screen resolution, not something flexible like browser viewport size, and so I would expect them to always be fixed.

Is it possible that the data I have is accurate, i.e. that these could all be from a single device? Or am I without doubt actually observing three different devices?

Googling reveals [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl/iewebdevelopment/thread/3b5b6a85-6c92-41b0-9b23-82bcde17e301) and [this](http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?showtopic=28247) which are examples of IE8's screen resolution reporting being inaccurate, but do not explain why the values might change over time. Are there other known issues with these variables?

Background is [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/39728/analytics-reports-multiple-different-screen-resolutions-for-apparently-a-singl), the screen.width variable is being called by Google Analytics code on user machines. I'm trying to understand the anomaly by eliminating possibilities as I think of them.

Comment: If memory serves, screen.width and screen.height give you the dimensions of the primary display. If you have multiple VDUs, they will always provide the dimensions of the primary one (the one with the task bar).

Comment: A width of 1366px is found on recent 10" or 11" netbooks. See [WXGA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_display_resolution#WXGA). 1140 or 1144 (?) was intermediate between 1024 and 1280, I used it a lot on Trinitron LCD monitors: I needed room so couldn't stand 1024px width but at 1280px the refresh rate wasn't good enough. I still can't figure where these weird heights could come from, except the tray bar.

Comment: Side question: why do you need screen resolutions in the first place? For clustering results or finer control?

Comment: I'm trying to determine exactly what individual users are doing for a research project - small enough number of users that with "days since last visit" analytics variable I can put together a visitor flow across multiple days but the results of that appear to show a single visitor with multiple different resolutions. So either my logic is wrong, or maybe this is normal and my self-assembled visitor flow is working.

Comment: so is screen resolution part of the data you actually want to look at, or are you just trying to use it as a way to show individual users? Because if it is the latter...why not just pop a custom variable on your site with a unique, persisting value (nothing personally identifying to the user though, that's against GA's ToS)

Comment: This is old data that I'm trying to understand. Hindsight is 20/20 and all that :/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact MSIE and Firefox adjust the physical screen resolution with the zooming factor being applied in the browser into the screen.width value.
This is why you get odd dimensions for MSIE and Firefox, but not Safari nor Chrome

See also [How to detect page zoom level in all modern browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers) about detecting zoom level per browser.

Comment: Thanks! That question doesn't explicitly mention screen width but a bit of reading between the lines lead me to this page which discusses the phenomenon you refer to: http://www.readableweb.com/forIEteam/IE8zoomanalysis.htm